# Kubernetes Pod unable to communicate with another Pod using a Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have 2 Pods with 1 container each. The container names are:

1. mc1
2. mc2

**mc1** container hosts an asp.net core razor pages app while **mc2** hosts a web api app. Now mc1 has to communicate with mc2 i.e. razor page app has to call web api app.

I have tried to explain it in the below image:
[image]

I created 2 deployments for these 2 pods:

```
name: dep1
labels:
    app: mc-app1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: mc-app1
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: mc-app1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mc1
          image: multiapp
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dep2
  labels:
    app: mc-app2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: mc-app2
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: mc-app2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mc2
          image: multiapi
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

I also created a service for the POD containing the mc2 container (i.e. web api app).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: multi-container-service-2
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mc-app2
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
```

The deployments and services are successfully applied to the k8s cluster.

Next, I am entering the container "mc1" and trying to curl the service called **multi-container-service-2** but this is not working.

I am getting error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to multi-container-service-2 port 80: Connection refused

In the below image I am entering the shell of the container **mc1** with the command:

```
kubectl exec -it dep1-5c78b8c889-tjzzr -c mc1 -- /bin/bash
```

[image]

In the next image I am doing the curl which is giving error:

[image]

Note that I have already installed curl using the 2 commands given below:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install curl
```

Why can't the app in mc2 container be called using the service? My Operating system is windows 10.

I am taking the help of these 2 tutorials:

1. [Build ASP.NET Core applications deployed as Linux containers into an AKS/Kubernetes orchestrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/containerized-lifecycle/design-develop-containerized-apps/build-aspnet-core-applications-linux-containers-aks-kubernetes)
2. [Communicate Between Containers in the Same Pod Using a Shared Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/)

Comment: Hi there. You've created a NodePort service. That's for exposing outside the cluster. Consider using `ClusterIP` instead. Now back to your problem. Have a look at the Endpoints `kubectl get endpoint`. You can then describe the endpoint created for that service. Basically when the service is created, a corresponding Endpoint is created. Check that it has the pod IP listed in the endpoint.

If it is there, check that your app is actually listening on :80. It might not be.

Comment: Another thing - when you curl you're actually hitting the `service`. The service is listening on 8080, not on 80. So you need to change your curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set to service port to `8080`, but you are calling the service on port 80 (which is the container's port).

This should work:

`curl http://multi-container-service-2:8080`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [official kubernetes documentation:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

> Kubernetes creates DNS records for services and pods. You can contact services with consistent DNS names instead of IP addresses.

In order to communicate Pod-to-Pod through a service in your cluster you have to use the following syntax :

`{service_name}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local`

So in your case, with curl it would be :

```sh
curl multi-container-service-2.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: I ran your command `curl multi-container-service-2.default.svc.cluster.local`. It also failed.

Comment: Is that the right namespace ? I mean are you in "default" namespace ?